# Input checked has not working in side partial in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m beginner in Angular. I m working on a angular project. I have a input checkbox in my partial source. When it checked a popup should appear, not checked state have a popup.

I found the below code on google and it works separately. But when i put it my partial source it doesn't work.

```
<div>
<div >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="A" ng-false-value="B" ng-model="check"/>        
</div>

<div ng-show="check == 'A'">
    Checked
</div>

<div ng-show="check == 'B'">
    Unchecked
</div>
```

Can you anyone help me

Comment: Do you have a property called "check" within your model, e.g. controller?

Comment: please provide the rest of the code too, controller, routes etc.

Comment: <section class="main" ng-controller="Common">
code are here
</section>

Comment: I wrote all my common stuffs in that "Common" controller..

Comment: Should i add anything for this input checkbox in that Common controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming You want to access the parent controller value inside partial which has been loaded using `ng-controller` directive, In that you need to follow dot rule in your code, As a `ng-controller` create a new child scope whenever it adds the specified template.

For solving issue you should have your data in object structure in-order to follow prototypal inheritance

**Code**

```
$scope.model = {};
```

**Markup**

```
<div>
<div >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="A" ng-false-value="B" ng-model="model.check"/>        
</div>

<div ng-show="model.check == 'A'">
    Checked
</div>

<div ng-show="model.check == 'B'">
    Unchecked
</div>
```

Other way to do it would be is you can simply use `$parent` before the `check` scope variable, that will refer to the parent scope of the controller.

Just replace `check` with `$parent.check` everywhere in the view, This will work but the first approach is most preferable.

Answer (score -1):

Add single quotes to 'A' and 'B'

```
<div >
    <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'A'" ng-false-value="'B'" ng-model="check"/>        
</div>
```

Comment: But my source i have already declared ng app in index.html and partial has the input checkbox... there it doesn't working

Comment: Try this it is working i just copied your code to Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/PPHL7Igyo6s0pbMsEHpZ?p=preview